# mysql query not searching properly for keywords

Tags: mysql

I am making a custom search system . i made the following query to search from two fields

```
SELECT * , CONVERT( description USING utf8 ) FROM phpbb_tube_items WHERE description LIKE  '%$search_keyword%' OR title LIKE  '%$search_keyword%'
```

but the problem is suppose when i search for "jenny" it works . but if a search for "jenny" and the string in database is "Hello Jenny" it does not works . I wanted to search for the word "jenny" weather its alone or in between of a string of words

Comment: What happens if you search for `Jenny's`? That is the correct notation for a substring match, though.

Comment: What type and collation are 'description' and 'title'?

Comment: if i search for the word jenny and if there is only word jenny stored in title or description then it works .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this to get info on case-insensitive MySQL searches http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-sensitivity.html

Obviously your search is case-sensitive and this is why you can not get 'Hello Jenny' as a match when searching for '%jenny%'

Comment: Thank you . This is indeed the perfect solution and it worked